# find all limit cycles of the system of nonlinear equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the task of finding the limit cycles of the nonlinear system of ODEs.  Further, I need to determine the stability and draw the phase portrait.
  of the system.
$$
x'=-y+x(1-x^2-y^2)(2-x^2-y^2)
\\
y'=x+y(1-x^2-y^2)(2-x^2-y^2)
$$
I used linearization, produced the Jacobian and came up with $\lambda_{1,2}=1\pm i$.

Then since the real parts of lambda are $>0$, the equilibrium is unstable.  My attempts to find the equilibrium are fruitless.  I tried converting to polar coordinates and obtained
$$
rr'=(2-x^2-y^2)(x^2-x^3-2x^2y^2+y^2-y^4)
$$
This does not at all seem helpful. How do I find the limit cycles?
I appreciate anyone that can help.

Comment: Polar coordinates is the right way to go. But you should be able to write the right-hand side in terms of $r^2$ alone (considering what the original equations look like), so that $x^3$ term must be a computational mistake.

Comment: You should get $rr'=xx'+yy'=(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2-1)(x^2+y^2-2)$, it is better to not multiply the factorization out..

Comment: Thank you so much!  Leaving the equation factored gave me r'=r(1-r^2)(2-r^2).  Thus, when r'=0, r=0, 1, =1, sqrt(2), -sqrt(2). Now I have something with which to work.